# Last Auto increment ID before insert query in Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I want to get last auto increment id in wordpress.so i have tried LAST_INSERT_ID();

```
$last_id = $wpdb->query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();');
$new_id = $last_id + 1;
```

but its not working and as per official mysql site : it will give id of most recently executed INSERT statement

Any other way to get id? pl help.

Comment: `LAST_INSERTED_ID()` works only if you already inserted the value. If you have an autoincremental ID column in your table I could suggest `SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl` and it should work

Comment: Be careful 
    `SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl` can return a value different than `LAST_INSERTED_ID()`

Comment: @Mark zucchini Yeah LAST_INSERT_ID will not work with my issue and i know about max(id). But any other way?

Comment: @BhumiShah None that I am aware of

Comment: If the LAST_INSERT_ID solves your problem then the answer below works.
If the LAST_INSERT_ID doesn't solve your problem change the question please?

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID doesn't work. I have already written my question that i have tried LAST_INSERT_ID but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

$wpdb->query function returns an integer value indicating the number of rows affected/selected. For CREATE, ALTER, TRUNCATE and DROP SQL statements, this function returns TRUE on success.

Use $wpdb->get_var function instead.

```
$last_id = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();');
$new_id = $last_id + 1;
```